# Public Hotspot not connecting

Tags: wifi

I recently installed Freya on my computer and removed Windows so the only OS I have is Elementary... I've been getting a problem where the laptop refuses to connect to BTWifi (large Isp in the uk) I can connect to any network with a password but I can't connect to networks without passwords. BTWifi requires you to log in through a web portal once you connect, however it's not connecting for me to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Elementary OS has an app to log on captive networks named capnet-assist, installed by default. Try launch it from terminal and look for any error.